# Secure Prometheus with google auth

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, prometheus, google-anthos

as part of anthos service mesh installation i included grafana and prometheus,
I was able to secure access to grafana using google.auth in grafana.ini file.
is there anyway i can secure access to prometheus as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common thing to use would oauth2_proxy though there are many options.

Comment: do you have any documentation on how to implement the oauth2_proxy and do you know if it's applicable when you have prometheus as part of anthos service mesh, Thanks

Comment: You would run it as a sidecar and rather than expose Prometheus directly, you expose it through the proxy.